# Joda LocalDate -- How to check if it's been 24 hours since an event

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Description: I'm making a mobile app for a client where inventory can be recorded, but two inventory records can't happen within 24 hours of each other.

Approach: I'm storing the inventory along with the date on Firestore as a string with format "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" at the conclusion of the process.

```
data class PastInventoryItem(
var username: String = "",
var date: String = "",
var countedquantity: ArrayList<Material> = arrayListOf()) : FireStoreData()
```

---

```
private boolean checkIf24HourReached() {
    db.collection("Project").document(Prefs.getString("ManageID",
            GlobalObject.FIRESTORE_ID))
            .collection("inventoryMode")
            .document(GlobalObject.INVENTORY_MODE_ID)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                    PastInventoryItem pastInventoryItem = documentSnapshot.toObject(PastInventoryItem.class);
                    if(pastInventoryItem.getDate().isEmpty()){
                        proceedWithInventoryMode();
                    }

                    LocalDateTime date = new LocalDateTime(pastInventoryItem.getDate());
                    Date today = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().getCalendar().getTime();

                    Date twentyfourhoursbefore = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().getCalendar().getTime();
                    twentyfourhoursbefore.setTime(twentyfourhoursbefore.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

                    return !(date.after(twentyfourhoursbefore) && date.before(today));
                }
            });

}
```

Problem: This code does not compile because the "after" and "before" methods are from **Java.Util.Date**. Is there any way to get a string and check if it's been 24 hours since a **LocalDate** value?

Comment: `yourLocalDateTime.plusDays(1)`

Comment: Have you tried to use startAfter() on the Query object?

Comment: Just a hint: No need to add Joda Time to your project. Since 1.8 Java has had its own powerful Date & Time API inspired by Joda Time.

Comment: Sorry, another hint: Why do you store it as a String? Firestore does support timestamps.

Comment: @McPringle my superior wanted to keep it that way, but I insisted to change it. I'll try the Java 1.8 Date.

Answer (score 0):

In LocalDateTime class, such method names are isAfter and isBefore, but you cant use Date class object as method parameter. You will have to use LocalDate or LocalDateTime object. below is the method snippet from LocalDateTime class for your ref-

```
public boolean isAfter(ChronoLocalDateTime<?> other) {
    if (other instanceof LocalDateTime) {
        return compareTo0((LocalDateTime) other) > 0;
    }
    return ChronoLocalDateTime.super.isAfter(other);
}
```